# Using QPainter transform for perspective projection

Tags: qt, 3d

Qt's `QPainter` draws on a 2D plane and is able to modify its coordinate system by `.setTransform()` in combination with `QTransform`.
The latter has a built-in kind of projection (using a constant distance to plane of 1024), for example used when rotating around the x-axis.
Is it possible to set the transforms to different z-Values in order to achieve a 3D projection (for example rotating a cube around its center x-axis, viewed from (0, 0,0))?
In `QTransform` doc it says: "Perspective transformation is achieved by setting both the projection factors and the scaling factors" [of the transform matrix]. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtransform.html#basic-matrix-operations
But what would be the math behind that?

Another solution could be using `QMatrix4x4` transformation and the `perspective()` and `toTransform()` functions to get a QTransform object. But thats seems even more complicated.

Comment: https://vertexwahn.de/2020/12/27/perspectiveprojection/

Comment: Unfortunately QTransform uses a 3x3 matrix. I wonder if there's a clever way to use 3x3 matrices to "fake" a 3D perspective projection. For example using different QTransform objects with different distances to the viewing plane (-> z values)...